# WPF: Textblock Font size should be even when its size change

Tags: wpf, textblock, font-size

I create a custom button in my application as following

```
<Button x:Class="MyApp.ButtonMainMenuSubCat"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="536">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid Name="gridParent">
                    <Image Name="imgTransparent" Source="/MyApp;component/Resources/LeftCategoryTransparent.png" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,0,0,0"  />
                    <Image Name="Part_Pressed" Source="/MyApp;component/Resources/PressedMainScreenSubMenu.png" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,0,0,4"  Visibility="Hidden"/>
                    <Image Name="Focused" Source="/MyApp;component/Resources/MainSubMenuFocus.png" Margin="-3,0,-3,3"   Stretch="Fill" Visibility="Hidden" />
                    <Image Name="Seperator" Source="/MyApp;component/Resources/MainSubMenuSeperator.png" Margin="5,0,5,-1"   Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

                    <TextBlock Name="lblTitle" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Foreground="Gray" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"   FontSize="24"  Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <!--<Setter TargetName="Pressed" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>-->

                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Focused" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="lblTitle" Property="Foreground" Value="#f8cb1c" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

In my application, I call web service and depending upon the no of items, i create button for each item and finally add these button in StackPanel. Its works well. Stakpanel layout is on left side in screenshot. Now problem is that when I run this application on different machine which have different Screen resolution (like 1920 *1200), then font size seems too small. So i want to adjust font size when container size change. One option is use **ViewBox** but in case of ViewBox all buttons seems like have different font size and TextWrapping is not possible.

So my actual requirement is that increase/decrease the textblock's font size with TextWrapping  and font size must be even for all buttons.

[image]

Comment: Have you concidered to use the scale transformation on your StackPanel?

Comment: i am new to WPF and never works on transformation. Could you elaborate some more or give any code snippet ? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a LayoutTransform based on the screen resolution, you can either scale up your stackpanel or scale up the whole window depending on the resolution.

For the stackpanel:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform  x:Name="ScaleTransform" />
    </StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
    <Button>A</Button>
    <Button>B</Button>
    <Button>C</Button>
    <Button>D</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Then bind the ScaleX and ScaleY to a formula based on the resolution. An example of this:

```
double scale = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight / 720;
//using 720p as the base screen height.

this.ScaleTransform.ScaleX = scale;
this.ScaleTransform.ScaleY = scale;
```

You may want to do this in a ViewModel with some databinding if you are using MVVM.

Comment: i use your code but it scales the button height. However you give me direction that how could i can scale font size of text block. so my problem is solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: i add following event in custom button         private void Button_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock lblTitle = (TextBlock)base.GetTemplateChild("lblTitle");
            double scale = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight / 731;
            if (lblTitle != null)
            {
                lblTitle.FontSize = 24.5 * scale;
            }
            
        }

Comment: LayoutTransform will also scale the font size! Try it with a more extreme transform (2 or 3)

Comment: i did not get you. What you mean from extreme transform(2 or 3) ?